# ifstream variable in class

Tags: c++, function, class, ifstream

I have my class which has to have ifstream file in it.

I dont know how to present it in the class header

A:

```
class MyClass
{
    ...
    ifstream file;
    ...
}
```

B:

```
class MyClass
{
    ...
    ifstream& file;
    ...
}
```

I know that ifstream has to get path in the decaleration, so how do I do it?

Also how do I open a file with it?

EDIT:

I want the first way, but how do I use it SYNTAX-ly?

let's say this is the header(part of it)

```
class MyClass
{
    string path;
    ifstream file;
public:
    MyClass();
    void read_from_file();
    bool is_file_open();
    ...
```

}

funcs

```
void MyClass::read_from_file()
{
    //what do I do to open it???
    this->file.open(this->path); //Maybe, IDK
    ... // ?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You more than likely want the first option. The second is a reference to some other `ifstream` object, rather than an `ifstream` that belongs to `MyClass`.

You don't *need* to give an `ifstream` a path immediately. You can later call the `ifstream`'s `open` function and give that a path. However, if you want to open the `ifstream` immediately on initialisation, you need to use the constructor's initialisation list:

```
MyClass() : file("filename") { }
```

If you need the constructor to take the file name, simply do:

```
MyClass(std::string filename) : file(filename) { }
```

Comment: So how can I open with it, when it try this->file.open it gives me errors

Comment: You would do `file.open("filename");` in the constructor, but you're better off using the initialisation list instead.

Comment: But it's a class, it's not a constant file

Comment: @user2410243 What do you mean by a "constant file"? Are you just asking why there is no `this->`? Doing `this->` is just not necessary in most cases; it would work with or without it.

Comment: This isn't what I asked. When I decelerate the ifstream - it's in the class and it should be by the path that I get in the constructor. I get a path that I should open the file with it.

Answer (score 0):

Initialise it in the constructor:

```
class my_class {
public:
    my_class(char const* path) : file(path) {

    }

    my_class(std::string const& path) : my_class(path.c_str()) {

    }

private:
    std::ifstream file;
};
```

Also see [*The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).